# can't get admob to work on ios8 app

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I've tried multiple tutorials and tried code in multiple places but can't get google admob to do anything. I get no errors, project builds and runs in simulator. No ads load and no message in debugger.
Basically nothing is happening.

I've added the following in my appDelegate

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADBannerView.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADBannerViewDelegate.h>
#import "Firebase.h"
```

and under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` I've put

```
[FIRApp configure];
[GADMobileAds configureWithApplicationID:@"ca-app-pub-5601547953982889~9365662253"];
```

in my `viewcontroller.h` I've also added

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADBannerView.h>
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GADBannerViewDelegate.h>
#import "Firebase.h"
```

added

```
@interface BT_viewController : UIViewController <GADBannerViewDelegate,
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet GADBannerView  *bannerView;
```

and

```
@protocol GADBannerViewDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;
- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)bannerView
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error;
- (void)adViewWillPresentScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;
- (void)adViewDidDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;
- (void)adViewWillDismissScreen:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;
- (void)adViewWillLeaveApplication:(GADBannerView *)bannerView;

@end
```

then in my view controller.m ive added

```
- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)bannerView {
bannerView.hidden = NO;
    [BT_debugger showIt:self theMessage:@"Google ad shown"];
}
- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)bannerView didFailToReceiveAdWithError:    (GADRequestError *)error {
NSLog(@"adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

and then under `-(void)viewDidLoad` I've added

```
self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                            self.view.frame.size.height -
                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.height,
                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                            GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
self.bannerView.delegate = self;
self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";

self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];

[self.bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Pretty sure i got it all covered but absolutely nothing is working. No errors, no degub, zip...

Please Help!

Comment: Did you implement Google Ad Mob functions yourself instead of installing it through Cocoa Pods?

Comment: please share your coca pods file , if you have done it manually, what all libraries added? Also share logs. usually logs shows message

Comment: ive implemented myself and added the following frameworks

Comment: GoogleMobileAds,FirebaseAnalytics,FirebaseCore,FirebaseInstanceID,GoogleToolboxforMac,GooglesymbolsUtilities. Logs as in my debug output? shows nothing about ads at all

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to try install with Cocoa Pods and still had the same result. Then I found in the GADbannerview file it had an example code to load ad. I tried this code and now ads are displayed!

```
 GADBannerView *adView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
adView.rootViewController = self;
adView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
///   // Place the ad view onto the screen.
[self.view addSubview:adView];
///   // Request an ad without any additional targeting information.
[adView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```